# Mocking addEventListener in created hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, mocking, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test an event listener in my `App.vue` `created` hook. The test passes the 1st assertion and fails on the 2nd. From what I can see in the terminal, the issue appears to be that the test is expecting `[Function mockConstructor]` but received `[Function bound mockConstructor]` as the 2nd parameter. I'm not sure what the issue is. Any pointers would be appreciated.

In `App.vue` component:

```js
  async created () {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.changeHandler);

    await someModuleFunction();
    someOtherModuleFunction();
  },

  methods: {
    changeHandler () { /* Function code here. */ },
  }
```

In `App.spec.js` test:

```js
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import App from '@/App';
import wait from 'waait';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
let windowSpy;
let mockAdd;

describe('app.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get');
    mockAdd = jest.fn();
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      addEventListener: mockAdd,
    }));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    windowSpy.mockRestore();
    mockAdd.mockRestore();
  });

  const shallowMountFunction = (options = {}) => shallowMount(App, {
    localVue,
    stubs: ['router-view'],
    ...options,
  });

  describe('created hook', () => {
    it('calls the expected functions', async () => {
      expect.assertions(2);
      const spy = jest.spyOn(App.methods, 'changeHandler')

      shallowMountFunction();
      await wait();

      expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalledWith('orientationchange', spy);
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue component methods are bound to an instance, it isn't expected that `this.changeHandler` is the same function that were provided in `methods`.

It is:

```
const wrapper = shallowMountFunction();
...
expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalledWith('orientationchange', wrapper.vm.changeHandler);
```